# How to connect a USB to SCSI-2 adapter to a SCSI-1 50 Pin Centronics Tape Drive?

Tags: linux, usb, adapter, scsi

I currently have a tape drive that looks like:

[image]

where the right side is a SCSI-1 50 Pin interface. I have at my disposal a few USB to SCSI-2 adapters, such as the iomega scsi to usb adapter, and the adaptec usb2xchange, which looks like this:

[image]

Both of these adapters have a SCSI-2 50 pin male interface.

What I would like to know is how to bridge the two. I would like to find a Centronics 50 Pin Female to SCSI-2 50 Pin Female adapter, but these do not seem to exist.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8206/148) recent answer on the retrocomputing stackexchange, which explains that conversion between SCSI-1 and SCSI-2 is possible, or ask your question there if you need more details.